# Cómo funciona este método? (Python)

Tags: python, poo, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy aprendiendo a usar tkinter en Python, asi que encontré un código de referencia pero tengo dudas con el método `switch_frame`.  Por qué en la variable `new_frame = frame_class(self)` está ese self? Cómo el método detecta el frame de las demás clases si la variable `self._frame` de la clase `SampleApp` es `None` y no está ligada a la clase `StartPage`? `master` influye en algo?

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk
    
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Start page", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to page one",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to page two",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageTwo)).pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='blue')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page one", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='red')
        tk.Label(self, text="Page two", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cuidado porque si seguis eliminando preguntas, el sistema te va a penalizar y no te va a dejar preguntar mas. Tene en cuenta eso. "Estoy aprendiendo a usar tkinter en POO" <- Sera en python (aunque no existe en otro lenguaje) POO es programacion orientada a objetos, y python es un lenguaje POO...

Comment: Perdón, es que es mi primera vez aquí. También corregí la descripción de la pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código es un poco farragoso de leer, pero se puede comprender lo que hace, si se lee en el orden correcto.

Cuando el programa arranca crea un objeto `app = SampleApp()` por lo que se ejecutará sin parámetros el constructor de `SampleApp` que es este:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)
```

Como consecuencia del cual se invoca su método `.switch_frame()` al que se le pasa como parámetro una clase, en este caso `StartPage`. Veamos entonces qué hace `.switch_frame()`:

```
    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()
```

Vamos por pasos. Primero ¿qué son los parámetros `self` y `frame_class` que está recibiendo? El primero es una referencia al objeto sobre el que se ha hecho la llamada. Este objeto es de momento el objeto `app` creado al principio. El segundo parámetro `frame_class` será el nombre de una clase, y en este momento la clase es `StartPage`.

Vemos que se hace `new_frame = frame_class(self)`. Ya que en este momento `frame_class` es `StartPage` y `self` es `app` según acabamos de ver, esa línea equivale a `StartPage(app)` en este momento.

Por consiguente se está invocando el constructor de la clase, pasándole como parámetro la app. Efectivamente si miramos cómo es el constructor de `StartPage` vemos que espera un parámetro:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
         ...
```

Así que se le está pasando la `app` como valor para `master`. De hecho todas las clases Frame implementadas siguen el mismo patrón. Todas tienen un constructor que espera el parámetro `master` y que sirve para relacionarlas con la app desde la que fueron creadas. Usarán ese parámetro para poder "volver" a la función `switch_frame()` de su "master" cuando tengan que cambiar de frame.

Pero sigamos con la función `switch_frame()`. Una vez se ha creado un nuevo frame y se ha "ligado" a la app actual a través de su parámetro `master`, el objeto resultante ha sido guardado en la variable `new_frame`. Seguidamente se hace:

```
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()
```

Se mira entonces si `app._frame` es distinto de `None` (en este momento no lo es, pues `None` es el valor que se le dio a `self._frame` en el constructor). Y después se reasigna `app._frame` para que sea el nuevo Frame recién creado (`StartPage`). La próxima vez que se invoque `switch_frame()` se encontrará que `self._frame` ya no es `None`, por lo que se ejecutará el `self._frame.destroy()` para destruir el frame anterior antes de asignar el nuevo.

Y este es básicamente el mecanismo que permite "cambiar de frame" que se resume por tanto en:

1. Crear un nuevo frame instanciando un objeto de la clase que haya recibido como parámetro (`StartPage` en este caso). En esa instancia se le pasa como parámetro al constructor el objeto `self`, para que el Frame tenga una referencia a "su padre" (`master`)
2. Destruir el frame previo si había uno
3. Reasignar `self._frame` para tener una referencia al nuevo frame (para poder destruirlo más adelante cuando se cambie por otro).

Y en efecto vemos que este método es invocado desde los botones, por ejemplo aquí:

```
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to page one",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack()
```

Ya que `master` es una referencia a `app` según vimos, se invoca el método `.switch_frame()` de la clase `SampleApp`, y se le pasa en este caso la clase `PageOne` para que se cree un nuevo Frame del tipo `PageOne` (destruyendo al frame que estuviera activo hasta ese momento).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.  Me sirvió muchísimo.

Comment: Me queda una duda: Cómo `self._frame` deja de ser `None`?

Comment: Hay una asignación `self._frame = new_frame` justo en la cuarta línea de `switch_frame()`

Comment: Edité este comentario. Entonces con sólo llamar al método la variable `self._frame` deja de ser `None`?

Comment: La variable `self._frame` de la aplicación contiene el último frame al que has cambiado. Es usado para destruir ese frame cuando cambies a otro. Al inicio vale None porque todavía no has cambiado a ningún frame, y se le da un nuevo valor cada vez que se llama a `switch_frame()`.

Comment: Comprendo. Gracias por responder.